# File upload with other fields

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I have an Html form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. I have an `dto` class it has all setter and getters. Since I am submitting form as `multipart`, `getParameter()` method will not work, so in `servlet` I used List as follow,

```
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem item : items) {
if (item.isFormField()) {
    // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
    String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
    String fieldvalue = item.getString();
    // ... (do your job here)
    //getters and setters

} else {
    // Process form file field (input type="file").
    String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
    String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
    InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
    // ... File uploading code
}
}
```

Here my problem is how can I call getters and setters in for loop. I think here it should be single statement that will apply to all parameters through for loop. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: what type is your dto class are you able to cast it to FileItem

Comment: @vikeng21 I dont knw about that but it is a java file having string type of variables and for that all getters and setters are there.

Comment: @vikeng21 Please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library such as [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/), for example:

```
if (item.isFormField()) {
    // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
    String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
    String fieldvalue = item.getString();

    BeanUtils.setProperty(dto, fieldname, fieldvalue);
}
```

Comment: k . . . what is dto here . .

Comment: is it object of my dto class. . .

Comment: yes, the object you want to call its setters and getters

Comment: and what are the jar to be use for this . .

Comment: I provided the link to the project web site, you can download the jar from there. Or if you use Maven, take a look at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.1

Comment: no I am not using maven so just commons-beanutils.jar is enough right . .

Comment: Thank u .. .It solved my problem . . now I have another problem related to this if u r intrested I ll ask?

Comment: you should probably ask it in a new question